# JkWorkersFile: Can't find the workers file specified

Tags: apache-2.2

I am trying to set up a simple horizonatal Tomcat clustering in windows XP.
Have created a workers.properties file in conf/ directory next to httpd.conf file. However, when trying to start apache using httpd.exe, I am getting the below error.

JkWorkersFile: Can't find the workers file specified

httpd.conf has below entry:

```
LoadModule jk_module modules/mod_jk.so
JkLogFile "logs/mod_jk.log"
JkLogLevel error
JkMount /TestProject loadbalancer
JkMount /TestProject/* loadbalancer
JkWorkersFile conf/workers.properties
```

I tried specifying the absoluate path as well 
i.e. 
    JkWorkersFile "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/conf/workers.properties"
But still ended up with the same problem.

Below are the entries from workers.properties
    workers.tomcat_home=$TOMCAT_HOME
    workers.java_home=$JAVA_HOME
    ps=/
    worker.list=tomcatA,tomcatB,tomcatC,loadbalancer

```
worker.tomcatA.port=8109
worker.tomcatA.host=localhost
worker.tomcatA.type=ajp13
worker.tomcatA.lbfactor=1

worker.tomcatB.port=8209
worker.tomcatB.host=localhost
worker.tomcatB.type=ajp13
worker.tomcatB.lbfactor=1

worker.tomcatC.port=8309
worker.tomcatC.host=localhost
worker.tomcatC.type=ajp13
worker.tomcatC.lbfactor=1

worker.loadbalancer.type=lb
worker.loadbalancer.balanced_workers=tomcatA,tomcatB,tomcatC
worker.loadbalancer.sticky_session=1
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this please ?

Answer (score 1):

Check permissions (ACLs), depending on how you start Apache, it might not be able to access that file you newly created.

Answer (score 1):

I saw this same issue today, although with Win7, not WinXP. For me, the issue was that my workers.properties file had accidentally been saved as a text (.txt) file instead of as a PROPERTIES file. I re-created it, then when saving, chose all file types instead of "text files" to make sure it saved as a .properties file.

When I restarted Apache, all was well. I know the post is old, but maybe this will help someone out looking for the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try to add the worker.properties file under the line of jk module

```
LoadModule jk_module modules/mod_jk.so
JkWorkersFile conf/workers.properties
```

After adding please restart the apache web server